# "Missing implementations" when using ClassTag

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement the following trait:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): M[A]
  def flatMap[A, B](ma: M[A], f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

for type Array:

```
def arrayMonad: Monad[Array] = new Monad[Array] {
  def pure[A](a: A): Array[A] = Array(a)
  def flatMap[A, B](a: Array[A], f: A => Array[B]): Array[B] = a flatMap f
}
```

The compiler complains that there are no ClassTags for A and B. If I add them (either with an implicit parameter or "[A: ClassTag]" style), I'm told that I'm missing implementations:

```
Missing implementations for 2 members. Stub implementations follow:
  def flatMap[A, B](ma: Array[A], f: A => Array[B]): Array[B] = ???
  def pure[A](a: A): Array[A] = ???
```

There may be something obvious I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add them, then you change signature and are no longer overriding the original methods (add `override` and you'll see "overrides nothing" error).

You simply can't implement `Monad[Array]` for this definition of `Monad`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple modification I can make to the definition of `Monad` to make this example (or one very much like it) work?

Comment: @A_P you can add the class tag constraints to the original Monad definition. But then, you would impose such constraints to all other implementations that do not need it. Why do you want to do this? Arrays are low level, usually reserved for performance sensitive where abstractions like monads doesn't make much sense, specially because they require mote boxing

Comment: It's part of an exercise I created to better understand some things around the free monad (which I'm implementing). As part of that, I've got a `foldMap` that requires a natural transformation `F ~> G` and an `implicit Monad[G]`. I've got a contrived example where `F` will be a list-like type and `G` will be `Array` (or `List` or similar).

Comment: @A_P just desist about `Array` use `List` or the new `ArrayaSeq`

Comment: @A_P Paremetrize `Monad` by `Obj[_]`, a predicate that selects a subcategory of the category of Scala types: `trait Monad[Obj[_], M[_]] { def pure[A: Obj](a: A): M[A]; def flatMap[A: Obj, B: Obj](ma: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B] }`. You then get `Monad[ClassTag, Array]`. To select the whole category as that subcategory, use a predicate that is always true: `type MonadAll[M[_]] = Monad[({ type L[x] = DummyImplicit })#L, M]`, so e.g. you still get `MonadAll[List]`, and, in general: `def upgradeMonad[M[_]](m: OldMonad[M]): MonadAll[M]`

Comment: @A_P Just saw the comments, and I concur with the others: if you need `Array`, use HTNW's solution, if "or `List` or similar" will do, don't use `Array`.

Comment: Thanks! I switched to List and it worked. (I posted this comment yesterday but it seems it disappeared.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps emulate Luis' contribution to cats [Adding instances for ArraySeq #3273](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/3273) and use [`untagged`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/97dbfeb78b75196f067c69b849e3c2f85e9c3891/core/src/main/scala-2.13%2B/cats/instances/arraySeq.scala#L40) factory to avoid having to provide implicit `ClassTag`:

```
def arrayMonad: Monad[ArraySeq] = new Monad[ArraySeq] {
  def pure[A](a: A): ArraySeq[A] = ArraySeq.untagged(a)
  def flatMap[A, B](a: ArraySeq[A], f: A => ArraySeq[B]): ArraySeq[B] = a flatMap f
}

arrayMonad.pure(42)
// res0: scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq[Int] = ArraySeq(42)
```